# Websocket Message Receiving Failed Detection

Tags: node.js, express, websocket

Here is ws library..
https://github.com/websockets/ws/blob/master/lib/WebSocket.js

Now How can I use send method such as i can detect the message sending failed? I have tried callback and try catch.. may be i am missing something..

Now I am doing this.. it can send the message..

```
BulletinSenderHelper.prototype.sendMessage = function(bulletin, device) {
    var message = JSON.stringify({
        action: 'bulletin:add',
        data: bulletin.data
    });

    if (device.is_active) {
        logger.debug('Sending message to %s', device.id);
        device.conn.send(message); // device.conn == ws . though i am checking it is active or not, sometimes it fails to send the message. i have to detect it.
    } else {
        logger.debug('Client %s is inactive, queuing bulletin', device.id);
        this.queueBulletin(device, bulletin);
    }
};
```

Comment: Implementing callback for send() does not help?

Comment: device.conn.send(message, function ack(error){ logger.debug("error %s", error); //others thing to do...}); // got undefined error msg always both for success and failure